# Can`t alter views filter option

Tags: views, hooks

I need to alter my view filter option!

The view must display some comments. Every comment, that I need, has  custom field "node reference". And I want to filter comments by this field.

E.g. if my view displays on page with node 9(nid), view should return me all comments where "node reference" = 9;

I have found such solution: http://www.drupaldump.com/view-3-alter-filters-programmatically

And try to rewrite for me:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view(&$view) {

  if ($view->name === 'contest_winners') {
    $view_filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');

    $node_id = arg(1);


    $view_filters['field_for_contest_nid']['value'] = null;
    $view_filters['field_for_contest_nid']['value'][$node_id] = inttostr($node_id);
    $overrides = array();
    $overrides['filters'] = $view_filters;
    foreach ($overrides as $option => $definition) {
      $view->display_handler->override_option($option, $definition);
    }

    dpm($view_filters); // here value = node_id, but view use default value

  }

}
```

But this does not help: view uses default value.

Maybe i have made some stupid mistake?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you read not complete article :(. before this method getting call we should tell hey views we want use your hooks

something like in your `.module` file

```
/**
* Implements hook_views_api().
*/
function yourmodule_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'yourmodule') . '/views',
  );
}
```

Then create a views directory, create `yourmodule..views.inc` file there and put your code there ( please be sure your code getting execution with some `dsm` or `die()` ).

I know your change your way but I think it help you in another task.

take a look  at : [this article](http://www.grasmash.com/article/demystifying-views-api-developers-guide-integrating-views)

Comment: thanks. It seems this is a solution. But I have already fixed it and don`t remember in which way

Comment: @Q-bart you're welcome,I post this maybe help another one in future.and if you think it's ok mark as accepted please.